# Any way to suppress @property warnings without @dynamic?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, properties, runtime

For one of my classes I'm providing the implementation of accessors for properties at runtime. The code runs fine and compiles, but I get warnings for not implementing methods for declared properties in the header file. I can obviously fix this with `@dynamic`, but if it works without it any way, is there any compiler flag I can turn on to just suppress such warnings?

Comment: So what do you think the purpose of `@dynamic` is then?

Comment: I've just realised there is another way to read this question.  Are you asking if there is a way to globally disable the warning so you don't have to go through the tedious business of adding @dynamic for all your properties?  If so, the answer is "stop being lazy" :-) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. That's the whole point of `@dynamic`.

Comment: +1 Yes, this question is asking "How can I suppress a warning without using the feature that is specifically designed to suppress that warning?"